# Нужно удалить все записи с базы данных у которых ref > 10 Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Нужно просто из контроллера удалить все записи с базы данных у которых ref больше 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не использовать модель, то за счет DAO будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
\Yii::$app
        ->db
        ->createCommand()
        ->delete('mytable', 'ref > 10')
        ->execute();
```

---

За счет модели

```
MyModel::deleteAll('ref > 10');
```

подготовленные переменные

```
MyModel::deleteAll('ref > :ref', [':ref' => 10]);
```

---

За счет `Query`

```
use yii\db\Query;

...        

(new Query)
    ->createCommand('DELETE FROM mytable WHERE ref > :ref');
    ->bindParam(':ref', 10);
    ->execute();
```